# How to include js file and initialize some function in jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

basically I have 2 problems with javascript and jsp file. First one concerns fact that I can't include externall js file into jsp file. Basic structure of my project looks something like this:

```
system.web
       |
      WebContent
         |
         js
           |
            nowa_postac.js
         |
         jsp
           |
            nowa_postac.jsp
```

nowa_postac.js has only

```
 init = function() {
    test();
}
function test() {
        var myObject = JSON.parse('${gson}', null);
        alert(myObject.rasy.rasaList.length);
        alert(document.getElementById("testowy").id);
    }
```

I include javascript inside nowa_postac.jsp with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/nowa_postac.js"></script>
```

but I can't call any function from nowa_postac.js in jsp file and

```
 src="<c:url value="/js/nowa_postac.js"
```

seems to be not working either...
test() returns nothing but alert(test) returns text, so javascript file is loaded...Also, everything works fine when test() is inside jsp file.

The second problem is about how to initialize function after the jsp page is loaded;

```
<body onload='init()'>
```

is not good here because in init() I need to refer to some objects created in jsp...
Thanks for any help

Comment: Watch the source code of the generated HTML page in your browser, and check if the JS file is correctly included in your page (decent browsers like Chrome or Firefox will make the URL in your `<script>` tag a clickable link, so you can reach it easily).

Comment: you should consider jQuery...you'll have a lot options with jQuery...note my response below

Comment: try src="${c:url('/js/nowa_postac.js')}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jQuery to answer this question.  First I have an external .txt file with the name includedScripts.txt which has the following format:

```
NameOfFile~pathToJSFile
```

For example:

```
nowa_postac~nowaPostAc.js
```

Note that nowaPostAc.js will be residing in a subfolder called **Scripts**.

Next I load jQuery (I'm assuming you know how to do this, if not you can read up on http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready#more-5) and in my jQuery file I have the following:

```
/*
    *
    * LOAD ADDITIONAL SCRIPTS
    */
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: 'Scripts/includedScripts.txt'
        , timeout: 5000
        , success:
            function (data) {
                myArray = data.split(/\n/);
                for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                    theContents = myArray[i].split("~");
                    goodToGo = false;
                    theFileName = "";

                    if (theContents.length == 1) {
                        goodToGo = true;
                        theFileName = theContents[0];
                    }
                    else {
                        for (var t = 0; t < theContents.length; t++) {
                            if (theContents[t].indexOf(".") != -1) {
                                theFileName = theContents[t];
                            }
                            else if (location.pathname.indexOf(theContents[t]) != -1) {
                                goodToGo = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (goodToGo == true) {
                        pathToScript = (theFileName.indexOf("..") >= 0) ? theFileName.replace("..", "") : "Scripts/" + theFileName;
                        script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.type = 'text/javascript';
                        script.src = pathToScript;
                        if (jQuery("#ctl01").length > 0) {
                            jQuery("#ctl01").append(script);
                        }
                        else if (jQuery(".page").length > 0) {
                            jQuery(".page").append(script);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        , error:
            function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert("Could not load additional modules, please alert IT");
                //make a log entry...
            }
        , async: false
    }); // load additional scripts
```

You will more than likely need to edit the lines:

```
if (jQuery("#ctl01").length > 0) {
                            jQuery("#ctl01").append(script);
                        }
                        else if (jQuery(".page").length > 0) {
                            jQuery(".page").append(script);
                        }
```

to possibly read something like:

```
if (jQuery("body").length > 0) {
                            jQuery("body").append(script);
                        }
                        else if (jQuery("SomeOtherDivOrClass").length > 0) {
                            jQuery("SomeOtherDivOrClass").append(script);
                        }
```

What the script does (in conjunction with the includedScripts.txt file) is allow you to specify a different script to be loaded based on the page.  This of course, assumes that you have a singular script that is loaded on all pages, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> src="Scripts/customeJQuery.js"></script>
```

which would have the above code (Load Additional Scripts).

This works for me, you'll have to do some tweaking - let me know if you get through.

Comment: well, I know not so much about JQuery, but your solution seems not to be working. I've changed '#ctl01' to 'body', commented the _else if_ part, put Scripts folder with txt file, nowaPostac.js and customJQuery.js into WebContent/jsp. in customJQuery.js I have your jquery code in _$(document).ready(function() {}_ block and in jsp file I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsp/Scripts/customeJQuery.js"> </script>`  and now both test() and alert(test) returns nothing...

Comment: ok, I've changed pathToScript and url variables and now it seems to work, but only in IE. Do you know what to do to make this work on other browsers? IE is kind of problematic because I usually work in linux

Comment: I'm not a big IE fan either, but it works for me in IE, Chrome, and FireFox.  I haven't tested in Safari but for all intents and purposes it should work.  That said though, you may need to clear your cache (I know, the old shutdown and restart comment) and see if that helps you out.  If there is any change, then possibile, jQuery(document.body).append instead...